# File is in use while deleting a video which is being played in html via video tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have a quick question.

I am using the "video" tag on my web page to display video from my server say "/videos/myvideo.mp4

Video is playing fine.

The issues is when I try to delete the video from some other code (server side)
via File.Delete(physical path) I am getting "File in use" error.

Is this a known issue?
How can I delete the video physically if someone is playing that video on his page at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem when trying to rename a file, using C# on Windows 7. I do have a feeling that the problem is not as severe now as it was when I wrote that code. I don't know if some Windows 7 patch has fixed it.

Some things to try:

- Ensure your OS is fully patched.
- Ensure the file is `Close`'d before attempting the delete.
- Set any variables that use the file to null.
- `Dispose` any variables that use the file.
- If you are **absolutely** sure nothing is holding the file open, you
  might need to write a loop to keep trying the `Delete`, say every few
  seconds. (Horrible fudge, it was the only thing that worked for me.)